# Update BKPF fields while posting a document after validation is successful

Tags: abap, sap-erp, function-module, badi

I have a requirement to update `XBLNR_ALT` field using a number range on the header `BKPF` when posting a document. This update needs to happen only after all validations are successful.

My requirement is to update the field using continuous number range. If this update happens before all validations are successful, a number from a number range gets created but is not used in case validation fails. This causes a **gap in the numbers** and I'm looking for ways to avoid that.

For example, the number range is from `0010000` to `0020000`.

##### Iteration 1

I'm trying to post a document.

- Substitution logic creates a number `0010001` and assigns to field `XBLNR_ALT`.
- Validation fails
- Document is not posted.

##### Iteration 2

I correct the validation errors and try to post the document again.

- Substitution logic creates a number `0010002` and assigns to field `XBLNR_ALT`.
- Validation successful.
- Document posted.

`XBLNR_ALT` on `Doc1` = `0010000`
`XBLNR_ALT` on `Doc2` = `0010002`

I have tried two ways to update this field:

1. By creating a substitution exit in `GBB1`. `XBLNR_ALT` was populated. However, this caused the number range to be not continuous as the validation exits are called after the substitution is done.
2. By creating a `BTE` - `00001120` DOCUMENT POSTING: Field substitution header/items. This `BTE` FM is also called before the validations.

Comment: is this a standard number range? I suppose the field `XBLNR_ALT` is standard